# using retrofit library for making Async request in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

**What I have** :: I have a simple Asynctask that uses Http to get the JSON

**What i am trying to learn**:: How to convert this into a project that uses `retrofit` library

i have mentioned the class below

---

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    JSONObject jsonobject;  
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    private String Content;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    //TextView txtSplashTitle,txtSplashDesc;

    @InjectView(R.id.txtSplashDesc) TextView txtSplashDesc=null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);//using ButterKnife library for viewInjection

        String serverURL = "";
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);

        freeMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        //Setting fonts for textviews
        setCustomFontForTextViews();

    }



    private void setCustomFontForTextViews() {
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "royalacid.ttf");
        txtSplashDesc.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }



    // Class with extends AsyncTask class
    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashActivity.this);


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
            Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // NOTE: Don't call UI Element here.
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:3009/findmybuffet/?storedproc=get_app_tables&flag=sudhakar");
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(Content);
                jsonobject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("findmybuffet");
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("buffets");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("buf_off_id", jsonobject.getString("buf_off_id"));
                    map.put("from_time", jsonobject.getString("from_time"));
                    map.put("to_time", jsonobject.getString("to_time"));
                    map.put("online_price", jsonobject.getString("online_price"));
                    map.put("reserved_price", jsonobject.getString("reserved_price"));
                    map.put("buf_image", jsonobject.getString("buf_image"));
                    map.put("res_name", jsonobject.getString("res_name"));
                    map.put("rating", jsonobject.getString("rating"));
                    map.put("latitude", jsonobject.getString("latitude"));
                    map.put("longitude", jsonobject.getString("longitude"));
                    map.put("buf_type_name", jsonobject.getString("buf_type_name"));
                    map.put("from_date", jsonobject.getString("from_date"));
                    map.put("to_date", jsonobject.getString("to_date"));
                    map.put("city_id", jsonobject.getString("city_id"));
                    map.put("city_name", jsonobject.getString("city_name"));
                    map.put("meal_type_id", jsonobject.getString("meal_type_id"));
                    map.put("meal_type_name", jsonobject.getString("meal_type_name"));
                    map.put("buf_desc", jsonobject.getString("buf_desc"));
                    map.put("distance", jsonobject.getString("distance"));

                    Log.d("----$$$----", map.toString());

                    //Calling database 
                    db.addContact(map);

                    //findCityName();
                    //String result=getAddress(12.918286,77.669493);
                   // Log.d("----result$$$$$-----", result);
                }           
            } catch (IOException|JSONException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String getAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(SplashActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);
                    result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    result.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            return result.toString();
        }

        /*private void findCityName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        }
*/
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {     
            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();   
        }
    }

    private void freeMemory() {
        jsonobject=null;
        jsonarray=null;
        arraylist=null;
        Content=null;
    }

}
```

---

**There are no errors, but how can i convert into a retofit project similarly**

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain the JAR file from http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Create an interface class (ClientInterface.java) with following code:

```
@GET("/findmybuffet/?storedproc=get_app_tables&flag={name}")  
void findBuffet(@Path("name") String name, Callback cb);
```

The implementation will look something like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setServer("http://10.0.2.2:3009")     
            .build();
ClientInterface service = restAdapter.create(ClientInterface.class);

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {
        // Read response here
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        // Catch error here
    } }; 
    service.findBuffet("sudhakar", callback);
```